# How to stay logged in for Awesomium?

Tags: c#, cookies, awesomium

I want to program an app with C# and Awesomium for remembering that a user is logged into the site. For this I use the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Uri link = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com");
    webControl1.Source = link;
     string Values="";
     WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession("d:\\temp", WebPreferences.Default);
    session.SetCookie(link, Values, true, true);

}
```

But when I close and run the app again, I must log in again.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're setting the last parameter to true in your call to the SetCookie function - This means you're setting a session cookie not a persistent cookie that will be saved to disk

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     Uri link = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com");
     webControl1.Source = link;
     string Values="";
     WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession("d:\\temp", WebPreferences.Default);
     session.SetCookie(link, Values, true, **false**);

}
```

Reference: See [here](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_WebSession_SetCookie)